# How to compress CSS

Tags: css, optimization

I've looked at half a dozen CSS optimisers out there.  What I'm looking for is one that will turn:

```
background-image: url(../images/background.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-color: #c0c0c0;
```

Into the single background property:

```
background: #c0c0c0 url(../images/background.png) repeat-x;
```

How can I do this?  Do I have to do it by hand?

Comment: good luck - that's more like refactoring than minification

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try [**http://www.cssoptimiser.com/**](http://www.cssoptimiser.com/)

**Input:**

```
body {
    background-image: url(../images/background.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
}
```

*(I ticked "Do not remove line breaks")*

**Output:**

```
body {
    background:#c0c0c0 url(../images/background.png) repeat-x
}
```

Note that it also optimised away the space - you asked for `background:<space>#...` :)

There may be other/better tools which can do this, but that site does fulfill your wish.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you also have gzip enabled on your server (or some other form of compression for text files).

Comment: A good point. You'll probably save much more from HTTP compression than CSS optimisation. A pedantic tip to squeeze every last byte out of your CSS size (if you're using HTTP compression) - use lowercase colours: don't use `#CFCFCF`, use instead `#cfcfcf` - that way the compression ratio will be slightly higher because you're more likely to have the characters `c` and `f` than `C` and `F` in your file, because everyone uses lowercase declarations, like `color: red`.